# Como enviar mensaje a una persona con websockets

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

estoy usando websockets en java jsp y me funciona perfecto puedo enviar y recibir mensajes por el momento si alguien envia todos ven el mensaje, mi pregunta es:
Como puedo hacer para que se pueda enviar un mensaje a un usuario especifico como en facebook selecciona un usuario y le envia un mensaje exactamente a esa persona ya teniendo una session de todos los usuarios, enviar un mensaje a ese usuario que ya tiene un ID session, mi codigo en el momento es asi.

Java Script

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Proyecto/Chats/" + nm.value + "/" + id.value);

websocket.onmessage = function (message) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.data);
    if (jsonData.message !== null) {
        // chats.value += jsonData.message + "\n";
        $("#plantilla").clone().appendTo(".chat");
        $('.chat #plantilla').show(10);
        //$('.chat .Nombre').html("Jonny");
        $('.chat #plantilla .mensajeria').html(jsonData.message);

        var formattedDate = new Date();
        var h = formattedDate.getHours();
        var min = formattedDate.getMinutes();

        Fecha = h + ":" + min;

        $('.chat #plantilla #tiempo').html(Fecha);

        $('.chat #plantilla').attr("id", "");

        $('.ch').text(1);
        $("#chatsgrup").animate({scrollTop: $('#chatsgrup')[0].scrollHeight}, 360);
    }
};



function chatAll() {

websocket.send(txtchat.value);
txtchat.value = "";


}
```

JAVA WEBSOCKET

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/Chats/{username}/{idusuario}") // Recibe nombre y id del usuario
public class CWebSockets {

    // === VARIABLES
    // Nombre de usuario y id de usuario.
    String nameuser, idusuario;

    // === Session del chat
    static Set<Session> chat = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    // === METODOS DE WEBSOCKETS
    @OnOpen // Maneja la conexion (Abre conexion))
    public void abrirConexion(Session userSession, @PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("idusuario") String id) {
        chat.add(userSession);

        // Crea las sessiones con nombre y id de usuario
        userSession.getUserProperties().put("username", username);
        userSession.getUserProperties().put("idusuario", id);

        // Asigna a las variables las sessiones especificadas
        nameuser = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("username");
        idusuario = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("idusuario");
    }

    @OnClose // Manejador de  remover session
    public void cerrarConexion(Session userSession) {
        chat.remove(userSession);
    }

    @OnMessage // Manejador de mensajes enviados
    public void manejarMensaje(String message) throws IOException {
        if (!message.equals("")) {
            Iterator<Session> iterator = chat.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                iterator.next().getBasicRemote().sendText(construirMensajeJson(nameuser, message));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te cuento mi experiencia y como lo solucione, primero que nada no se mucho de java, pero puedo contarte como resolví mi problema, en mi  modelo de usuario tengo un campo `socket` con el id del socket, ese id lo obbtengo cada vez que el usuario ingresa a la aplicacion o recarga la pagina, cuando quiero enviar un msj a un usuario en especifico, lo unico que hago es buscar el id del socket del usuario al que se lo voy a mandar y, esa linea seria asi `io.to(id del socket de la persona que lo va a recibir).emit ( 'mensaje a enviar' )`, esto lo hago yo con javascript, no se si sera lo mismo

Comment: pero de todos modos, supongo que ya tienes una idea de lo que intento decirte

Comment: Hola @Enzo , si tenia mas o menos pensado que era desde js ya que es el que muestra los mensajes en la vista, lo que te entiendo hay es que eb ese io.to debo recibir el id del usuario que recibe el mensaje mas el mensaje, si estoy bn con solo eso te funciono ??

Comment: Si, esa fue mí solución, había visto tutoriales, busque en Youtube en Google y no pude encontrar ninguna solución, hasta que se me ocurrió hacer eso y me funcionó, espero que te haya funcionado a ti también